# In my camera application I am getting IllegalStateException for some of samsung devices. As that code is working fine with other devices

Tags: android, camera, video-capture

**In Some of samsung devices setAudioEncoder method through IllegalStateException**

```
private void releaseMediaRecorder() {

 if (mediaRecorder != null) {
      mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
      mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
      mediaRecorder = null;
      camera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
    }
  }

  private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    camera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);

    mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(_instance.get());
    mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(_instance.get());
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    CamcorderProfile cf = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
    if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_1080P)) {
      cf = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_TIME_LAPSE_1080P);
    }

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(cf);

    File videoDirectory = FileUtility.getCameraDocsFolder(_instance.get(), 2);

    if (!videoDirectory.exists()) {
      videoDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    currentVideoUri = videoDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + FileUtility.getAttachmentFileName(2);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(curentRotation);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(currentVideoUri);
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(Constants.MAX_DURATION_RECORD); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(Constants.MAX_FILE_SIZE_RECORD); // Set max file size 50M

    try {
      mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
      releaseMediaRecorder();
      return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      releaseMediaRecorder();
      return false;
    }
    return true;

  }
```

**Logcat**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
       at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.java)
       at com.ms.engage.ui.CameraActivity.prepareMediaRecorder(SourceFile:976)
       at com.ms.engage.ui.CameraActivity.startVideoRecording(SourceFile:1199)
       at com.ms.engage.ui.CameraActivity.onTouch(SourceFile:910)
       at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9138)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2676)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2347)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2687)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2362)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2687)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2362)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2687)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2362)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2687)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2362)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2687)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2362)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2687)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2362)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2687)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2362)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2687)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2362)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2739)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1832)
       at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2979)
       at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2700)
       at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9354)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4975)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4736)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4268)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4321)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4287)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4413)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4295)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4470)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4268)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4321)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4287)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4295)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4268)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6865)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6746)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6717)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6955)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java)
       at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6926)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6978)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:558)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6838)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Can you post your logCat too.?

Comment: I updated my logcat